# Javascript - Convert specific Object to another type of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object in JavaScript like this :

```
var myObject = [
  TextRow {
    signal_market: 'KAVAUSDT',
    signal_initial_price: 4.1886,
    signal_last_price: 4.1886
  },
  TextRow {
    signal_market: 'HARDUSDT',
    signal_initial_price: 1.5181,
    signal_last_price: 1.5181
  }
];
```

I wonder how i can convert this object to another Object like this :

```
var myObject = {
  KAVAUSDT: {
    signal_market: 'KAVAUSDT',
    signal_initial_price: 4.1886,
    signal_last_price: 4.1886
  },
  HARDUSDT: {
    signal_market: 'HARDUSDT',
    signal_initial_price: 1.5181,
    signal_last_price: 1.5181
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd use [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
myObject.reduce((acc, curr)=> ({
     ...acc, 
     [curr.signal_market]: curr
}), {})
```

Comment: JavaScript! Or: how I started loving one liners with at best n^2 performance. Why should you create a full copy of the object at each iteration when `acc[curr.signal_market] = curr; return acc;` does the same without any copy?

Comment: Yes that's a good point. If your software is supposed to launch a rocket to Mars, you might want to use an old fashion for loop instead of using reduce, as it is more performant (assuming you want to use js). Otherwise you can take whichever makes you and your team happier  :)

Comment: It dos not work properly. can you please write the full code?